# Angle between Kinect line of sight and Head joint

Tags: kinect

How to find out the angle between Kinect's line of sight and Head joint. I have tried a lot, but i couldn't succeed. I have no clues, what to do next.

please Help me to figure out the way for finding out this angle.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly, but it should be pretty easy.

The head joint has 3 coordinates (X,Y,Z). Z is the distance from the kinect depth camera. 
You can consider the kinect depth camera as lying in the (0,0,0) of the world. This means that  the center of the depth image is the origin.

In that case, you can use Atan2 to calculate the X and Y angles like this:

```
X angle = atan2(headjoint.Position.Y, headjoint.Position.Z);
Y angle = atan2(headjoint.Position.X, headjoint.Position.Z);
```

- I use atan2 instead of atan because it saves you from a division to zero crash in case the Z values are 0. Atan2 knows how to handle this case.
- These resulting angles are given in radians.
- The X angle means a rotation around the X axis.
- The Y angle means a rotation around the Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei's answer is correct but the X and Y angles are the wrong way round.

If you want to find out the angle of the player in the X axis (using c#) do:

```
xAngle = Math.Atan2(headjoint.Position.X, headjoint.Position.Z);
```

To find the angle in the Y axis do:

```
yAngle = Math.Atan2(headjoint.Position.Y, headjoint.Position.Z);
```

This was very useful to me as I was trying to stear the audio beam towards the player. Cheers!

Comment: Rotation around an axis means moving a point in a plane perpendicular to that axis (or otherwise put, a plane whose normal = the axis). If you write atan2(x, z), you are effectively calculating an angle in the XOZ plane. A rotation in this plane is called rotation around the Y axis.